# Pass session ID to multiple PHP scripts within on HTML page

Tags: php, ajax

I have a single HTML page that uses a carousel style log in system. Each step in the sign up works off of a different php script. There are 3 forms on the page that appear as the user progresses through the sign up. As they progress I need to keep their user id from the first step in a variable in order to update parts of their account later on.

The forms are executed via ajax and the first php script calls

```
session_start();
```

And then sets the session variable

```
$_SESSION['user_id']=$account_id;
```

As I progress through the form I put this at the top to check if the session variable was passing through

```
if (empty ($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
$message = 'Cant find the session id';}
```

And it is not. I don't have session_start() at the top of the other php scripts.

Am I misunderstanding how to pass this variable?

Comment: `I don't have session_start() at the top of the other php scripts.` You answered it yourself, if you don't have it initiated how do you expect it to work? By calling `session_start()` at the top of your script you're allowing it to read the session that has been previously saved from another step of your code.

Comment: You have to write session_start() in the next page also, so that it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_start();` needs to be called at the beginning of each page load in order to make `$_SESSION` available.

Don't worry, it won't reset the session. In the simplest terms, `session_start()` just tells PHP that you are expecting a session to exist, and it needs to run its code to give you access to it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on session_start() not resetting the session